# Perl save a section of hash to a new hash

Tags: linux, perl

#### Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = {
    foo => {
        bar => {
                baz => "hi"
            }
        }
    };

my @arr = qw/foo bar/;
```

---

#### Question

Is there any way in perl to build up a hash ref string/identifier using an array/hash to specify the keys?

So with the above code I would want to take the strings from `@arr` and use them to generate the string

```
my $newhash = $hash->{'foo'}->{'bar'};
```

This is just an example and the number of nested hashes could be variable

---

Tried

So I know that if I knew the level of nesting then I could just use

```
my $newhash = { map { $_ => $hash->{$_} } qw/some values/ };
```

but I can't seem to come up with a way when the nesting isn't known.

#### Extra

```
perl 5.20
```

Any more info needed please ask.

Comment: @HåkonHægland How did you find that?

Comment: I remembered I commented on the question, so then I could easily find it on google by including my name in the search :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland ah cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk down thru the hash tree.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# always use these two
use strict;
use warnings;

# use autodie to automatically die on open errors
use autodie;

my $hash = {
    foo => {
        bar => {
                baz => "hi"
            }
        }
    };

my @arr = qw/foo bar/;

my $hash_ref = $hash;
for my $key ( @arr ){
    $hash_ref = $hash_ref->{$key};
}
# $hash_ref is now at the end of the array

print Dumper( $hash_ref );
```